# How to upgrade Magento 1.6 to magento 1.9

Tags: php, css, html, magento

I am having my current website running on Magento 1.6. I am looking to upgrade it to 1.9 but don't know how to start. I went through the below articles but was not able to move ahead.

http://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-development/upgrade/how-to-upgrade-magento/

http://www.crucialwebhost.com/kb/installing-magento-via-ssh/

Can anyone please help me from ground level. I need to know it from scratch. I wanted to replace the below code but was not able to locate the file in my database. I am currently using filezilla to access my server file. My database is maintained by a different company called nexcess.

```
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/index.php/getmagento/1.9.1.0/magento-1.9.1.0.tar.gz
wget http://www.magentocommerce.com/downloads/assets/1.9.0.0/magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0.tar.gz
tar xvf magento-1.9.1.0.tar.gz
tar xvf magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0.tar.gz
mv magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0/media/* magento/media/
mv magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0/magento_sample_data_for_1.9.0.0.sql magento/data.sql
mv magento/* magento/.htaccess .
mysql -h DBHOST -u DBUSER -pDBPASS DBNAME < data.sql
rm -rf *.sample magento/ magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0/
rm -rf magento-1.9.1.0.tar.gz magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0.tar.gz data.sql
```

**Please help me how to go through with it**

Comment: filezilla is an ftp client, what you are showing are command line commands. So your question does not make a lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 20):

```
Upgrade Roadmap for CE 1.9.0.1 from 1.6

1) take a backup of current database and current 1.6 code.
2) download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3) remove all folders and files from your 1.6 code (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.
4) now from your 1.6 merge your following folders into the 1.9
    - Community app/code/community
    - Local app/code/local
    - Media 
    - your theme or package (app/design/frontend/default/<ur theme> or app/design/frontend/<your package>)
    - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
    - copy your custom xml files from app/etc/modules/ to current app/etc/modules/
    - any custom admin theme folder from adminhtml/default/yourtheme.
    - copy your custom folders from adminhtml/default/default/ (1.6) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9).
    - custom js files if any from app/js/.
5) now go to app/etc/local.xml.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6) now check the site.it done.`enter code here`
```

P.S. for more information check my answer on http://magento-online-tutorials.blogspot.in/2015/06/magento-upgrade-from-17-to-19.html

Comment: I also update via Connect, all files are deleted. Now I'm uploading 1.9 files to my server. And saw your message, so I'm on right way.

Comment: It worked for me - it's worth pointing out that any custom rules added to the htaccess will need manually adding to the new file - almost caught me out

Comment: Any template you are using will need to be upgraded to use formkeys, otherwise your add to cart, registration, etc. will fail mightily.

Also, test any custom modules you created and upgrade any third party modules to versions that will run on 1.9.x.x 

Time to fire up a dev or staging server so you don't break your source of income.

Do not upgrade your live site until you can successfully run your dev/staging site without any bugs. Test everything! Otherwise you'll become yet another statistic.

Comment: Nice guy!
Saved my life! hehe

Answer (score 2):

Any template you are using will need to be upgraded to use formkeys, otherwise your add to cart, registration, etc. will fail mightily.

Time to fire up a dev or staging server so you don't break your source of income.

Answer (score 1):

Use The  Below terminal commands

```
chmod 550 mage

./mage mage-setup .

./mage config-set preferred_state stable

./mage sync

./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

php shell/indexer.php reindexall
rm -rf downloader/.cache/ var/cache/
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy you can upgrade with magento Connect.

Choose : Mage_All_Latest then click upgrade. It will automatic upgrade to latest version magento.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried using Magento Connect (`System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager` if you've never used it before) to do the upgrade?  I just did it from 1.6.2 to 1.9 two weeks ago, and it went just fine for me.  Very simple, didn't require any SSH.

Comment: Magento Connect Manager is never a recommended way of upgrading Magento.

Comment: @TigerOfAsia - Heh, for every one successful Magento Connect upgrade, there tended to be three fails if the upgrade woes over on the MagentoCommerce forums meant anything before they got shuttered.

Comment: Highly not recommended to follow this way !!